# Time comparison in windows batch script

Tags: batch-file

I run this script in windows batch

```
set currentTime=%TIME%

if %currentTime% lss 09:00 echo "Before 09:00"
```

and I get

> 60 was unexpected at this time.

If I remove the second % my script runs but it incorrectly returns "Before 09:00"
no matter what time I compare. (I think it compares 09:00 with the literal %currentTime).

Can anyone help on how to properly compare time?

Comment: I think `lss` is only for windows cmd/bat file `if`, not for bash. Don't know the equivalent, sorry, but hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Windows [tag:batch-file] is ***not*** equal to [tag:bash]!

Comment: You can't compare dates/times just like that, because there are no such data formats; all batch scripts can compare are strings or integers; I'm almost sure your date format is something like `h:mm:ss,cc` (`cc` are hundredths of seconds), and the `,` causes the problem here as it's a standard token separator (like also the space, for example). Even if there was no comma, the comparison will result in unexpected results as dates/times are just seen as strings (since they are not pure integer values)...

Comment: @aschipfl there came the code came out to solve/handle string by integers... you to know this... for mostly case, code solve limitation by imagination and technical knowledge, also, this is a good place to do this, not eventually, but continuously *sorry my English*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an easy way to do it in a `cmd.exe` shell .bat file script.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('powershell -NoL -NoP -Command "(Get-Date).Hour"') DO (SET /A "HOUR=%%a")
IF %HOUR% LSS 9 (
    ECHO "Before 09:00"
)
```

Comment: Since there are **no** strings and numbers in setting variables in batch file, you don't need to use `set /a`.

Answer (score 1):

For use pure bat to do this, you need use  **`EnableDelayedExpansion`** and use substring in time set, and work with if time layout are or not using AM/PM by change if from **`leq`** to **`gtr`** in **`%_bit_compare%`** to parse the procedure, or...

> It is some like another thing, that my limited **English** don't help me to explain to you very well, sorry..:

```bat
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "currentTime=!TIME::=!" & set "currentTime=!currentTime:,=!" & set "conpareTime=900"
(set "_bit_compare=leq" & time /t | findstr /l "AM PM" || set "_bit_compare=gtr" )>nul
if "!currentTime:~0,4=!" %_bit_compare% "!conpareTime!" (echo/ !time:~0,5! Before 09:00) else (echo/ !time:~0,5! After 09:00)
```

> Or, same code *in non-compacted form*:

```bat
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "currentTime=!TIME::=!" 
set "currentTime=!currentTime:,=!"
set "_bit_compare=leq"
set "conpareTime=900"

(time /t | findstr /l "AM PM" || set "_bit_compare=gtr")>nul

if "!currentTime:~0,4=!" %_bit_compare% "!conpareTime!" (

    echo/ !time:~0,5! Before 09:00

    ) else (

    echo/ !time:~0,5! After 09:00

    )
```

Comment: What happens if the `%TIME%` variable output isn't in 24 hour clock format?  e.g. `8:35`, not only would there be an issue with the first `5` characters not containing what you were expecting, you'll not know if it is `AM` or `PM`, and therefore whether `09:00` passed 11 hours and 35 minutes ago, _i.e. `after`_, or if the time `09:00` is due in `25` minutes, _i.e. `before`_.

Comment: @Compo Thank you appointment here, so, the time (in 24h) show space when echo/!time:~0,5!, but, where came out when are set AM/PM, I’ll see..

Comment: @Compo please, see the answer, if are treat time layout in 12/24 attempt to be precisely by this last update.. Thank you anyway..

Answer (score 1):

You may also do this as follows:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Set time to compare to 09:00:00:
set "time_to_compare=090000"

:loop
for /F "skip=1 delims=." %%A IN ('wmic OS get localdatetime') do (
    for /F "delims=" %%B IN ("%%A") do (
        set "_time=%%B"
        if !_time:~-6! GEQ 090000 (call :after) else (call :before)
    )
)

:after
echo It is after 09:00:00^^!
pause>nul
exit /b 0

:before
echo It is before 09:00:00^^!
pause>nul
exit /b 0
```

I don't know what you want to do. So, if it after, it will **`call`** — not **`goto`** — `:after` subroutine and if before, it will `call` `:before`.

You can make any other changes you want.

*Note: The time will be generated with the 24-hour and `HH:mm:ss` format; if you meant `21:00:00` change `set "time_to_compare=090000"` to `set "time_to_compare=210000"`*. The way this happened is to prevent misbehaviours. The solution is written in pure batch as requested.